# How do I change skins in minecraft pe?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I change skins in Minecraft PE for Android?

Comment: I would be looking forward to an answer for this, if it's even possible.

Comment: Something seems weird with, but give this a try. http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Skin-in-Minecraft-PE

Comment: What version of android do you have is it: <= 4.0?

Answer (score 4):

Since 0.11 just came out, here is a easy way to do it.

1: Press the settings button on the title screen of Minecraft PE.

2: Press the second option of the settings menu. (It should look like 4 skins)

3: Select your skin!

ALSO, if you want CUSTOM skins (Which I think you want), here is a easy guide.

1: Go to this website: http://minecraft.tools/en/skin.php

2: Enter the username (I will be doing notch for example)

[image: Entering in a username.]

3: Press the download button.

[image: Showing the download button.]

4: Now, you might have to download the picture manually, (depends on what device you have), if you do, do it as you would normally do it (Since I dont know all the ways devices download pictures.)

5: Do the process that I did at the top, and press the "Browse" option.

6: Select your skin that you downloaded.

7: Success! Hopefully you successfully imported a skin into MC PE!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you need an Android device

1. Download an app called Skinstealer
2. Look for a skin you like
3. Click "apply skin" or something like that
4. Click uninstall Minecraft (it will come just wait)
5. You will then see "do you wanna install Minecraft"; click it
6. Open Minecraft and your done!

Answer (score 0):

Skin support as an official feature in Pocket Edition is [planned for version 0.11](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_mentioned_features#Skins_.26_capes).

Answer (score 0):

**Skin support was officially added with the release of update 0.11.** To change your skin in the Settings menu, you can either choose from one of the available sample skins or set a custom one from any image file that uses the correct layout for a skin.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.11.0 on,there is a panel on the options screen with skins. Use it to change your skin,from Steve to Alex or select another skin by pressing "Custom". You must have images with skins for the "Custom" option to work.

Answer (score -2):

As of the current version, you cannot do this.  There will be an update soon that may address this.